# An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

when running the code i am getting the following error on insert

```
An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.
```

my code

```
using (PostDBDataContext dataContext = new PostDBDataContext())
{
    if (posttypeedit.posttypemeta != null)
    {
        foreach (var posttypemeta in posttypeedit.posttypemeta)
        {
            PostTypeMeta _postmeta = new PostTypeMeta();
            _postmeta.vcr_MetaKey = posttypemeta.Metatexts;
            _postmeta.vcr_MetaValue = posttypemeta.Datatypes;
            _postmeta.int_ModifiedBy = Authorization.UserID;
            _postmeta.dtm_ModifiedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            psttyp.PostTypeMetas.Add(_postmeta);
        }
    }
    dataContext.PostTypes.InsertOnSubmit(psttyp);                
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are inserting `psttyp`

```
InsertOnSubmit(psttyp);
```

but ptsstyp is not new so you cannot insert it again,

If your intention is just to **add** PostTYpeMeta's to your existing psttyp you can remove

```
dataContext.PostTypes.InsertOnSubmit(psttyp);
```

completely.